# Magento2 Download Pdf

Tags: magento2

I am creating invoice and shipments pro-grammatically its working fine now i want to download PDF also how can i achieve this in magento2 ?

Comment: Check this blog post https://dev98.de/2017/09/10/get-pdf-files-by-magento-webapi/

Answer (score 1):

you can use dompdf extension for magento, please check on this link to install to your magento project and how to use it :

https://github.com/weprovide/magento2-module-dompdf

Answer (score 0):

> **Try this code for create and download PDF**

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Zend_Loader;

class GetPdfData extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
     */
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\DirectoryList
     */
    protected $dir;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\DirectoryList $dir,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) {
        $this->dir = $dir;
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->initializePDF();
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $pdfData = [];
        $pdfData["body_data"] = "<h1><b>TEST Data</b></h1>";
        $config = [
            'mode' => 'utf-8',
            'format' => 'A4',
            'default_font_size' => 10,
            'default_font' => "dejavusans",
            'margin_left' => 1.5,
            'margin_right' => 1.5,
            'margin_top' => 1.5,
            'margin_bottom' => 1.5,
            'allow_charset_conversion' => true,
            'orientation' => 'P',
            'showBarcodeNumbers' => false,
            'tempDir' => $this->dir->getPath('var'),
        ];
        $pdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf($config);
        $pdf->WriteHTML(html_entity_decode($pdfData["body_data"]));
        $outputData = $pdf->Output('test.pdf', 'D'); // I , F , S
    }

    /**
     * Initialization of mpdf library
     */
    protected function initializePDF()
    {
        error_reporting(0);

        $path = $this->dir->getRoot() . "/vendor/mpdf/mpdf/src/";

        $this->pdf = $path . 'Mpdf.php';

        //include_once $this->pdf;
        Zend_Loader::loadFile($this->pdf, null, true);

        $this->config = $path . 'Config/ConfigVariables.php';

        // require_once $this->config;
        Zend_Loader::loadFile($this->config, null, true);

        $this->ucdn = $path . 'Ucdn.php';

        // require_once $this->ucdn;
        Zend_Loader::loadFile($this->ucdn, null, true);

        $this->defaultCss = $path . 'Css/DefaultCss.php';

        // require_once $this->defaultCss;
        Zend_Loader::loadFile($this->defaultCss, null, true);

        $this->sizeConvertor = $path . 'SizeConverter.php';

        // require_once $this->sizeConvertor;
        Zend_Loader::loadFile($this->sizeConvertor, null, true);

        $this->colorconverter = $path . 'Color/ColorConverter.php';

        // require_once $this->colorconverter;
        Zend_Loader::loadFile($this->colorconverter, null, true);

        $this->gradient = $path . 'Gradient.php';

        // require_once $this->gradient;
        Zend_Loader::loadFile($this->gradient, null, true);

        $this->tableOfContents = $path . 'TableOfContents.php';

        // require_once $this->tableOfContents;
        Zend_Loader::loadFile($this->tableOfContents, null, true);

        $this->cache = $path . 'Cache.php';

        // require_once $this->cache;
        Zend_Loader::loadFile($this->cache, null, true);

        $this->fontCache = $path . 'Fonts/FontCache.php';

        // require_once $this->fontCache;
        Zend_Loader::loadFile($this->fontCache, null, true);

        $this->fontsFileFinder = $path . 'Fonts/FontFileFinder.php';

        // require_once $this->fontsFileFinder;
        Zend_Loader::loadFile($this->fontsFileFinder, null, true);

        $this->cssManager = $path . 'CssManager.php';

        // require_once $this->cssManager;
        Zend_Loader::loadFile($this->cssManager, null, true);

        $this->otl = $path . 'Otl.php';

        // require_once $this->otl;
        Zend_Loader::loadFile($this->otl, null, true);

        $this->form = $path . 'Form.php';

        // require_once $this->form;
        Zend_Loader::loadFile($this->form, null, true);

        $this->hyphenator = $path . 'Hyphenator.php';

        // require_once $this->hyphenator;
        Zend_Loader::loadFile($this->hyphenator, null, true);

        $this->tag = $path . 'Tag.php';

        // require_once $this->tag;
        Zend_Loader::loadFile($this->tag, null, true);

        $this->namedcolors = $path . 'Color/NamedColors.php';

        // require_once $this->namedcolors;
        Zend_Loader::loadFile($this->namedcolors, null, true);

        $this->pageformat = $path . 'PageFormat.php';

        // require_once $this->pageformat;
        Zend_Loader::loadFile($this->pageformat, null, true);

        $this->fontVariables = $path . 'Config/FontVariables.php';

        // require_once $this->fontVariables;
        Zend_Loader::loadFile($this->fontVariables, null, true);

        $this->textvars = $path . 'Css/TextVars.php';

        // require_once $this->textvars;
        Zend_Loader::loadFile($this->textvars, null, true);

        $this->border = $path . 'Css/Border.php';

        // require_once $this->border;
        Zend_Loader::loadFile($this->border, null, true);

        $this->logcontext = $path . 'Log/Context.php';

        // require_once $this->logcontext;
        Zend_Loader::loadFile($this->logcontext, null, true);

        $this->ttfontfile = $path . 'TTFontFile.php';

        // require_once $this->ttfontfile;
        Zend_Loader::loadFile($this->ttfontfile, null, true);

        $this->destination = $path . 'Output/Destination.php';

        // require_once $this->destination;
        Zend_Loader::loadFile($this->destination, null, true);

        $this->mpdfexception = $path . 'MpdfException.php';

        // require_once $this->mpdfexception;
        Zend_Loader::loadFile($this->mpdfexception, null, true);

        $this->metricsgenerator = $path . 'Fonts/MetricsGenerator.php';

        // require_once $this->metricsgenerator;
        Zend_Loader::loadFile($this->metricsgenerator, null, true);

        $this->GlyphOperator = $path . 'Fonts/GlyphOperator.php';

        // require_once $this->GlyphOperator;
        Zend_Loader::loadFile($this->GlyphOperator, null, true);

        $this->barcode = $path . 'Barcode.php';

        // require_once $this->barcode;
        Zend_Loader::loadFile($this->barcode, null, true);

    }

}
```

**Note: MPdf is installing via composer require mpdf/mpdf command which placed into the vendor directory.**